# How to configure a custom context/dial plan for incomming calls in Elastix/FreePBX?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, elastix

I would like to know how set a custom context from the extensions.conf file, to deal with the incoming calls in Elastix/FreePBX?

I have developed a custom dial plan called [my-custom-incoming1] and I would like it to be called form every incoming call. There is an option called 'set destination' under the Inbound Routes, but I don't understand how to set a custom dialplan from this menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no need for creating an additional menu entry.
Just add `context=my-custom-incoming1` to your trunk definitions.

Comment: Are you saying to put the context definition inside the trunk on the PEER Details or on the USER Details box? Can you give and example or screenshot?

Comment: If your trunk is already configured, you can just add a context line into a section that you have already filled in.
`context` setting means "send incoming calls into this context".
So basically if you have configured your trunk filling in `PEER details` only, you add a context line into it. If you have configured a trunk with both `PEER details` and `USER details` filled in, you can add `context=my-custom-incoming1` into the both sections.

Comment: Ok! And what option do I choose for the "set destination" config in the inbound routes? Leave it blank? What does the "set destination" config does? Sorry about the many questions!

Comment: You can create any inbound route and choose any destination you want.
Then to make a call go through inbound routes, just add `exten => _X.,n,Goto(from-pstn,${EXTEN},1)` at the end of `my-custom-incoming1` context